# Агрегация или композиция?

Tags: c++, ооп

Помогите, пожалуйста, что лучше использовать в данном случае, агрегацию или композицию?

1. Создать следующие классы: Недвижимость (наименование, Цена, размер, адрес, Площадь, Удобства, Ремонт, Телефон) Показ (Недвижимость Агент, Клиент, Дата показа, Результат).
2. Вывести данные о классе Недвижимость.
3. Стоимость квартиры увеличить на 2 тыс.
4. Вывести перечень недвижимости, с площадью более 100 квадратов, которая находится в Ленинском районе города.
5. Удалить информацию по критерию.

Comment: Ну если у вас показ включает недвижимость, но недвижимость не зависит от показа, и может быть показана неоднократно (разным клиентам, например) - то что это - композиция или агрегация? См., например, https://habr.com/ru/post/354046/, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: Агрегация, конечно. Спасибо. Статью прочитал, но были сомнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку композиция - когда включаемый объект не существует отдельно от включающего, а недвижимость может существовать и не будучи показанной (независимо от показов), здесь следует применить агрегацию.